# Visual Studio 2017 can not deploy the application

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

I have just installed Visual Studio 2017 with Xamarin for building applications. I used to use Android studio which I have it also in my Laptop. I created a layout for my Android but I can not deploy it neither in my physical device nor the emulator. I could find my app in the Settings of my phone but the app could not launch. When I ran it on the emulator I received this in the log.I use google emulator

```
 Access to the path 'Mono.Android.Export.dll' is denied.
 2>Done building project "App2.csproj".
 2>Build succeeded.
 ========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
 ========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

can anyone help me please?

Comment: Did you try to run visual studio as Administrator?

Comment: yes I tried many things. I also tried vs emulator but still the problem remains

Comment: Just restart your computer and try again.

Comment: I have done it several times, tried clean the solution and build it also many times. I also followed some solutions that found in the site but nothing

Comment: Are you getting any error messages at all or just that it failed as shown?

Comment: thanks for your time, no I do not receive any error message. I am thinking of installing Xamarin studio to try there..